# How to position element on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This problem sounds trivial, but i got headache trying to solve it. I downloaded this free and simple menu from [javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/) (code is included on the page). It's ok, it works fine, but i don't know what should i change in order to make it align in different way. As you can see from the example, dropdown menu (shown when user position his mouse over top menu) has the same left margin as top menu (top menu, for example "help" is LEFT-aligned with corresponding dropdown menu).

What should i do in order to make dropdown RIGHT-aligned - align RIGHT margin of dropdown menu with right margin of top menu (for example, right margin of "help" dropdown to be aligned with right margin of "help" button).

In some c-like language it would be easy: `dropDiv.left=(TopDiv.left+topDiv.width)-dropDiv.width` but i have no idea how to do it for that menu from page i'v posted.... :\

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

use tables, you can align all your elements as desired..!

Answer (score -1):

In the `<style>` block (included in your `<body>` section), under `#sddm div a` simply change `text-align: left;` to `text-align: right;` and then your listed menu items will align right.

Comment: The question isn't how to right-align the text, it's how to position the menu so that the right edge lines up with the right side of the button.